# Codeigniter,create tables and users for MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to create databases and users with CI programmatically. So far i have these 2 simple MySQL statements.

```
CREATE DATABASE `testdb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

and

```
CREATE USER 'test_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '***';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'test_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '***' WITH GRANT 
OPTION MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 
MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0 ;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `testdb` . * TO 'test_user'@'%';
```

Can those be converted to Active Record, or does CI provides its own way of creating users/tables? i search the docs and couldn't find anything...

**EDIT**: I do this as an intranet application so no worries about permissions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CodeIgniter provides a class called as [Database Forge](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/forge.html) , it contains some functions which can be used to perform basic maintenance on your DB.

```
$this->load->dbforge()

if ($this->dbforge->create_database('my_db'))
{
    echo 'Database created!';
}
```

and regarding adding users, its possible, but I don't know if its a good practice or not.

and also make sure that the mysql user who runs the queries has the permissions to create db.

```
$data = array(
   'Host' => 'localhost' ,
   'User' => 'krish' ,
   'Password' => 'somepass',
   'Select_priv' => 'Y',
   'Insert_priv' => 'Y'
);

$this->db->insert('mysql.user', $data);
```

Comment: thanks,Krish, but from the first checks it only provides a way to create tables,not users

Comment: edited the answer..but I really donno if its a good practice or not.

Comment: it works but i had to change `db->insert('user', $data);` to `db->insert('mysql.user', $data);`

Comment: thanks and accepted:) just don't forget to correct your answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

IF I understand, you can try

```
$config['database'] = 'mysql';
// other config details e.g username. port, pass

$this->load->database($config);
$query = "INSERT INTO user (host, user, password, select_priv, 
          insert_priv, update_priv) 
          VALUES ('localhost', 'user', PASSWORD('mypass'), 'Y', 'Y', 'Y')";
$this->db->query($query);
```

My syntax might be a little off.

Essentially - use the `mysql` database, insert directly in to the `user` table.

Some hosts may deny access to this directy, however.

Comment: hmmm, smart :) just like i updated on my question,no permission problems...i will try your logic out and let you know if it works

Comment: thanks Ross,it works, but i will accept Krish's answer since it's more complete.thanks again