# Create table and grant permission to new user

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

With codeigniter I would like to have something similair to: [Codeigniter,create tables and users for MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440447/codeigniter-create-tables-and-users-for-mysql)

But I need to add new table with new user and password.
Like

```
$this->load->dbforge()

if ($this->dbforge->create_table('my_db'))
{
    echo 'Database created!';
}
```

and add premission with new user and pass to table: 'my_db' as only reading (SELECT)!
If someone can help me with this it should be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have not used CodeIgniter, but I think you can use something like this -

```
$this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE');
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html

And here it is script example -

```
CREATE USER 'user1'@'%'; -- specify new account - user name + host name
SET PASSWORD FOR 'user1'@'%' = PASSWORD ('pwd'); -- set password
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE db_name.table_name TO 'user1'@'%'; -- grant SELECT privilege
```